# Chatbot in Prolog

Tags: prolog, chatbot

I've been trying to create a chatbot (as an assignment) in prolog, so far I have made a database in a .pl file and I have listed a lot of possible conversations. 
I know that prolog works like this for example if we have

```
Chatbot(good)
```

and we type

```
?-Chatbot(good).
```

it will respond

```
yes or ture.
```

Now I don't know how to use my database so that the program can work exactly as a chatbot for example without the need to write in appropriate syntax:

```
Hello (typed by the user)

Hi there, (typed by the program automatically)
```

My database is like this:

```
answer( question, [
[Yes, I am here]]).

question ([are you there?])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype [chatbot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot) I'm aware of is [ELIZA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) by Weizenbaum 1966.

Implementing it in Prolog is rather easy, as shown in *The Art of Prolog* by Sterling & Shapiro.

Googling for 'ELIZA Prolog', the first link gives you a fairly complex [implementation](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2110-003/documents/eliza.pl), and you could adapt/reuse the engine with your database. But this way you will lose all the fun. I suggest you read the book and take the time to implement your own.

*edit*

Just in case you haven't still seen it, SWISH offers [a clean, barebone ELIZA](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/eliza.pl) implementation among [its examples](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/examples.swinb).