# Editing Eliza chatbot in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've been struggling trying to edit Eliza chatbot in Prolog. every time I try to edit something, a new error show up. Is it protected to  any sort of editing?

I edited using SWI-prolog editor. The problem is that I'm trying to minimize the code without fully understanding it. I'm trying to do a simple short version of it. So, I might removed something essential perhaps! like "my_char_type" for example. The error I got is " retract/1: No permission to modify static procedure `rules/1'"

Is there any code for a smaller chatbot that I can understand?

Please help :'(

Comment: Please help us understand your issue by providing more information like how did you edited it and what error did it throw.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have edited the post. I hope you can help:)

Answer (score 2):

Prolog has a static store and a dynamic store. If you open up a file, say `program.pl` and you put some lines in it like this:

```
foo(tabitha).
foo(darlene).
```

those facts wind up in the static store. They're not a mutable part of your program (by default).

The `asserta/1`, `assertz/1` and `retract/1` and `retractall/1` procedures form the basis of the dynamic store. If you are just sitting at the console you could just add some facts to the dynamic store and remove them by doing something like this:

```
?- asserta(baz(tabitha)).
true.

?- baz(X).
X = tabitha.

?- retract(baz(tabitha)).
true.

?- baz(X).
false.
```

However, if you are sitting at the prompt after loading `program.pl` and you try to retract `foo(tabitha)` you're going to get the static procedure message:

```
?- retract(foo(tabitha)).
ERROR: retract/1: No permission to modify static procedure `foo/1'
ERROR: Defined at /Users/fusion/program.pl:1
```

The reason is because the `foo/1` facts were placed in the static store rather than the dynamic store, because you didn't put them there with `asserta/1` or `assertz/1` or declare the predicate as dynamic, like this:

```
:- dynamic foo/1.
```

So there are two ways forward:

1. Edit the program source directly and reload it.
2. Declare the `rules/1` predicate dynamic as above.

Incidentally, reloading in SWI-Prolog is best done by running `make.` from the prompt.

I would recommend option #1 since otherwise it will be difficult to reconstruct your working program's state when you like what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

SWISH has the [simplest Eliza](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/eliza.pl) ever, I have the old code below, used to test my [Prolog interpreter](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL).

here is an example session

```
1 ?- eliza.
? i am hungry
how long have you been hungry ? 
? very long
please go on 
? bye
Goodbye. I hope I have helped you
true.
```

SWI-Prolog tested version, ported from below ELIZA.IL (alas, SWISH is apparently missing IO primitive like read_line_from_codes, so it's simpler to paste the full code)

```
eliza :-
    write('? '), read_word_list(Input), eliza(Input), !.

eliza([bye]) :-
    write('Goodbye. I hope I have helped you'), nl.
eliza(Input) :-
    pattern(Stimulus, Response),
    match(Stimulus, Dictionary, Input),
    match(Response, Dictionary, Output),
    reply(Output),
    !, eliza.

match([N|Pattern], Dictionary, Target) :-
    integer(N), lookup(N, Dictionary, LeftTarget),
    append(LeftTarget, RightTarget, Target),
    match(Pattern, Dictionary, RightTarget).
match([Word | Pattern], Dictionary, [Word | Target]) :-
    atom(Word), match(Pattern, Dictionary, Target).
match([], _Dictionary, []).

pattern([i,am,1],[how,long,have,you,been,1,'?']).
pattern([1,you,2,me],[what,makes,you,think,i,2,you,'?']).
pattern([i,like,1],[does,anyone,else,in,your,family,like,1,'?']).
pattern([i,feel,1],[do,you,often,feel,that,way,'?']).
pattern([1,X,2],[can,you,tell,me,more,about,your,X,'?']) :- important(X).
pattern([1],[please,go,on]).

important(father).
important(mother).
important(son).
important(sister).
important(brother).
important(daughter).

reply([Head | Tail]) :-
    write(Head), write(' '), reply(Tail).
reply([]) :- nl.

lookup(Key, [(Key, Value) | _Dict], Value).
lookup(Key, [(Key1, _Val1) | Dictionary], Value) :-
    Key \= Key1, lookup(Key, Dictionary, Value).

read_word_list(Ws) :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Cs),
    atom_codes(A, Cs),
    tokenize_atom(A, Ws).
```

Older code: [eliza](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL/blob/master/scripts/eliza.il) and [rwl](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL/blob/master/scripts/rwl.il)

Comment: Sir, first i would like to say thanks for an older comment for you that helped me to find the code for the original Eliza chatbot! Now, i'm not good at all in Prolog, i just have this for a single assignment. I tried your code in both SWISH and SWI-prolog, but it did not work. I wrote the word "bye" but it didn't respond :( Can you please tell me what version on SWI are you using? and also, what's the right way to add more rules to in this cahtbot without making errors. Thanks for your time sir.

Comment: I tested it in SWI-Prolog, latest version, but I'm fairly sure it will work in any version around. In SWISH - as I said - seems there are no input facilities... You should save the code above in a file named (just to say) eliza.pl, then in SWI-Prolog prompt: `?- [eliza], eliza.` To debug,, enter `?- leash(-all), trace.` before starting `?- eliza.`. Adding rules to the chatbot can be tricky, if you don't still understand how the code works

Comment: OK thanks, it worked. But what is the right way of writing the commands? I mean writing "bye" without any formatting style didn't work. Is this gonna be like the original Eliza or not? Many thanks!

Comment: The original Eliza was a complex program in Lisp. I don't know to which Prolog program you're referring. I posted in [SWISH](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/yet%20another%20eliza.pl) a working code, just wrap phrases on input with single quotes

Comment: i'm referring to your comment on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656390/chatbot-in-prolog?rq=1 I also noticed that you added this (use_module(library(readutil)).)  ! Now, SWISH pops up a window saying "Entering a Prolog query" every time i hit RUN

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't remeber I posted that link. The program run out-of-the-box in SWI-Prolog, I just added `:- dynamic(mem/1).` immediately after the other :- dynamic

Comment: Thanks for being so patient. Now, after entering ?- leash(-all), trace. can you provide me with an exact world with its format that could be understood by this program?

Comment: I don't get your last question... it's a chatbot, just enter some text and see what you get. The code I posted above it's simpler, but the idea it's quite the same.

Comment: in your code, you have programmed that if the user enter the word "bye", the program is going to respond by typing "Goodbye. I hope I have helped you". However, when I type "bye" nothing appear on the screen. I wish that I can get any contact of you to send you a screen capture. Thanks

Comment: try adding at end of program `..., tokenize_atom(A, Ws),writeln(Ws).` to see what is going on. Or `..., tokenize_atom(A, Ws),trace.` Then edit your question with the output...

Comment: Should the bye command for example be `?- bye` or `?- eliza([bye], Response).` ? I tried both of them and did not get an answer. I know I'm asking too much, but can you change the code and add more rules like response to "sorry" or "how are you" because I couldn't figure out the general pattern of this simple code.

Comment: I've pasted above a mini session example. Happy you find the code simple, merit of curse goes to mr. Shapiro. The key is usage of integers as positional keys to connect 'stimolus/response' parts over the simplest dictionary of 'sensitive data'. It's really simple, no need to assert/retract anything...

Comment: I see that you edited your answer, but I don't see any modification in the code above! I got the idea that the code integrate my input with the output. But please correct me if i'm wrong >> first, I need to type `?-leash(-all), trace.` and then to test one of your commands "bye" for example. I should write `?-bye` right? Could you add one more rule like response for "sorry" to your code. i really need to see that. thank you.