# How do I change all elements in list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to complete an assignment for a lite version of Eliza through Prolog. I need the program to display a prompt in which the user types in a sentence  as a list and the program will respond to the sentence derived from the original sentence. In the sentence, 'you' is changed to 'I'. 'I' is changed to 'why do you', 'are' is changed to 'am not', 'do' his changed to 'no, '. etc..

Below is the program however it only allows for the user to input one word. If I write 'you' only it works. However I get an error if I try to write a whole sentence or a word with [] surrounding.

"change(X,Y):- X = 'you', Y = 'I'.

change(X,Y):- X = 'i', Y = 'why do you'.

change(X,Y):- X = 'are', Y = 'am not'.

change(X,Y):- X = 'do', Y = 'no'.

change(X,Y):- X = 'portuguese', Y = 'russian'.

eliza:-

```
nl,

write("Ready> "),

read(X),

change(X,Y),

write('Eliza: '),

write(Y),

nl,

eliza.
```

:- initialization(Eliza).

May you inform me of what I need to change. Specifically which part and what it would look like.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbyuR.png

Comment: Have you Googled for Eliza examples? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179839/editing-eliza-chatbot-in-prolog

Answer (score 0):

`read(X)` is for reading Prolog code terms, not general text. You would have to enter something like `[you,are,portuguese]` to make a list of atoms.

Then you need to apply `change` over all of the atoms in the list, which you could do with recursion but is less code to use `maplist(change, X, Y)`.

And you may want a fact `change(X,X).` at the end, so that unknown words can pass through unchanged.

---

To go past that, you might use `read_line_to_string(user_input, Text)` instead of `read(X)` and `split_string/4` to split on spaces and turn it into words, and then change your facts to use strings instead of atoms or pay atention to converting between strings and atoms, and then apply change to them, and then use `atomics_to_string/3` to build the response string before writing it.